# Convert time into datetime which returns today's date and time from database

Tags: sql, time

How can I convert time into `DATETIME` which returns today's date and time from database?

Let's say I have time only in my database. `12:30 PM`, when I use:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, a.Start Time)
```

It always returns `1900-01-01 12:30:00.000`. Is there any way I can get today's date?

like :

```
2013-07-11 12:30:00:000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), (cast(getDate() as date) + cast(tm as datetime)), 120)
               from yourTable
```

**outPut: 2013-07-11 12:30:00**

check to see if it matches your requirement

[**Chek TO see SQL FEEDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c63b/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @currDate DATETIME;
@StrDate VARCHAR(30),
@StrTime VARCHAR(30)

SET @currDate = GETDATE();

SET @StrDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @currDate , 101);
SET @StrTime = CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.StartTime,108)
SET @StrDate = (@StrDate + ‘ ‘ + @StrTime);
RETURN CONVERT(DATETIME,@StrDate,121);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some nice *low-cast* (tm) version of that you need:

```
DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + a.Start Time
```